# SpringBootTest loads unwanted beans which are not included in ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am writing a Spring Boot integration test. Here I want to exclude several beans. So I am trying to load only as many beans as are required for my tests. For that I am using `@COntextConfiguration` and specifying only those classes which I want.

Despite of doing this I can see Spring Boot is still loading all other beans. Like for e.g it is loading `RetryTemplateConfig` which is present in a different package altogether. I used `@ComponentScan` to scan only current package and not the one in which RetryTemplateConfig lies. Still I get bean configuration errors. Below is my top section of my test class

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Import(BulkExceptionClosureTestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml", properties = {"INSTANCE_ID=1","spring.profiles.active=test","ENV=test"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BulkExceptionClosureApplication.class, ClosureRequestCsvFileProcessor.class,
        MetadataFetcher.class, XmlProcessingService.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.barclays.exceptionclosure")
public class BulkExceptionClosureTest {
```

And I get below error when starting this test.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'retryTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/xyz/validation/config/RetryTemplateConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
```

I have not included this class in my ContextConfiguration, still it gets loaded. Also `@ComponentScan` doesn't seem to work, as `RetryTemplateConfig` is in `com.xyz.validation` package. And my test class is in `com.xyz.exceptionclosure` package

What can be done to definitely load only the required beans for my test? Please not I cannot add `@Profile("!test")` on classes which I don;t want in Spring Boot integration test. Those are from library I cannot modify.

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` will detect your application and will load a full context for an integration test. Adding `@ComponentScan` to a test class is useless. Remove `@RunWith` (I assume you are on JUnit 5 with this), remove the `@ContextConfiguration` remove `locations` from `@TestPropertySource` and `spring.profile.active` (that is taken care of by the `@ActiveProfiles`. Don't try to load just a subset of beans, you end up with a lot of small tests which load each their own context (which is slow) instead load the context once and reuse (automatic with Spring Testing support).

Comment: No but this is what I want to do. I have some configuration classes which connect to DB and Kafka. I want to mock them. That I do in `TestConfiguration`. Apart from this, I need to exclude some beans which are loaded from external dependency. How can I do that?

Comment: What I am taking integration test approach is, I can use multiple inputs and get full coverage by running handful of tests in a single test class. Except those config classes which I want to exclude. Otherwise I need to write too many Mockito based unit tests to cover each and every class.

Comment: You can still add/load that additional configuration (not sure why but alas), also why would you need to exclude those other beans? You alredy use a profile, you can exclude hem from certain profiles or the config class.

Comment: You alredy use a profile, you can exclude them from certain profiles --> how to do this? One way I know is to add @Profile annotation on those classes. But I cannot do that. As there's a dependency I use which has some spring beans. They are auto loaded.

Comment: So you don't want to load them but still load beans which have a dependency on them? That is weird. To me it all feels you are trying to shoehorn `@SpringBootTest` into something it shouldn't be used for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation will not help when also using `@SpringBootTest`. `@SpringBootTest`'s classpath scanning takes precedence and your custom `@ContextConfiguration` will not be processed.

You can use a `org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.TypeExcludeFilter`.

On your `@SpringBootTest` annotated integration test add a `@TypeExcludeFilters(YourCustomTypeExcludeFilter.class)` annotation and it will use your implemented `TypeExcludeFilter` to filter out beans you don't want from the test's ApplicationContext.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TypeExcludeFilters(YourCustomTypeExcludeFilter.class)
public class MyIntegraiontTest {

    @Test
    public void integrationTest() {
        ...
    }

}
```

A simple `TypeExcludeFilter` that excludes beans by class name is the one below:

```java
public class YourCustomTypeExcludeFilter extends TypeExcludeFilter {

  private static final List<String> beanNamesToExclude = List.of(
      "org.personal.MyRabbitMqListener");

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj != null) && (getClass() == obj.getClass());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return getClass().hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) {
    return beanNamesToExclude.stream()
        .anyMatch(beanName -> metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName().equals(beanName));
  }
}
```

Sky's the limit on the logic you can use with the `match()` method.
For some more inspiration of what is possible just search for classes that extend `TypeExcludeFilter` in the Spring Boot source code (for instance look at `org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.TestTypeExcludeFilter`, a filter that's used to exclude `@TestConfiguration` annotated classes)